# Mui5 TextField Invalid prop `autoComplete` of type `boolean` supplied to `ForwardRef(InputBase)`, expected `string`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this textfield with an autocomplete and why is this throwing a warning?

```
<TextField
                type="text"
                id="standard1"
                label="Email"
                fullWidth
                required
                autoComplete
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you provided `autoComplete` as prop without any values, which is same as `autoComplete={true}`.

From the MUI docs `autoComplete` is of type "string"

See [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#props) and [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mui](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/) `autoComplete` is a prop of `type string` that helps users to fill forms faster it just specifies whether your input field should have  autocomplete on or off.

So just **change :**

```
<TextField
                type="text"
                id="standard1"
                label="Email"
                fullWidth
                required
                autoComplete
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
```

**to :**

```
<TextField
                type="text"
                id="standard1"
                label="Email"
                fullWidth
                required
                autoComplete='on'
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
```